# C Clipboard updating very slow

Tags: c, windows, clipboard

I want to monitor key events given to another application, and whenever ctrl+d is pressed, send ctrl+c, grab the (new) clipboard content and depending on it perform other actions.

My code:

```
void PressKeyboardKey(char key){
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wVk = key;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.dwFlags =  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ){
char pressedKey;
// Declare a pointer to the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTdsad
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKeyBoard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
switch( wParam )
{
case WM_KEYUP:
   {
    pressedKey = (char)pKeyBoard->vkCode; //get the key code
    if ((pressedKey == -94) || (pressedKey == -93)){    //Ctrl
        CtrlPressed = FALSE;
    }else if (pressedKey == 68){    //d
        if (CtrlPressed && IsTargetApplicationActive()){
            PressKeyboardKey(67);  //c
            //Read from Clipboard
            Sleep(CLIPBOARD_SLEEP_TIME);
            HANDLE h;
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL)){
                break;  //abort
            }
            h = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
            const char* output = evaluateItem((char*)h);  // For now prints the content of the clipboard
            Sleep(ADDITIONAL_SLEEP_TIME);  //Ususally not there, added just for testing
            CloseClipboard();
            .....
}
```

If CLIPPBOARD_SLEEP_TIME >= 350 (minimum), everything works as expected, tough the time is too long for a good workflow. Otherwise, I only get the old clipboard content.

My first guess was, that the target application fills clipboard very slow, however the following ahk script:

```
^d::
Send, ^c
MsgBox, %clipboard%
```

works seemingly instantaneous.
Therefore there must be a faster way to grab the clipboards content.

Anyone knows how to do it in C - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Keyboard input is buffered, you have no idea exactly when the target app will retrieve the keystroke from the message queue.  There is no reasonable upper limit, it can take *seconds* when the app has been swapped out of memory.  Clearly you are doing it wrong, anything else is better.  Not limited to SendMessageTimeout() to send the WM_COPY message and using UI Automation.

Comment: Wow, SendMessage really works wonders. My reason for SendInput, was it being THE thing popping up in google when looking for "send keyboard press c" - didn't know that this is such a bad idea.

Comment: I assume this is Windows. Would be helpful to add that keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `SetClipboardViewer()`, don't use `Sleep()`